# Get last 6 month data, If data is not available then print monthname and 0

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to get last 6 month data from oracle DB. I am able to get month data only if data is present, My requirement is to get all six month data, if data is not present then query should return month name and value  0.

Expected result
January 1000
February 0
March 0
April 0
May 1200

Getting result
January 1000
May 1200

Following is the query i am trying to get this.

```
select
  to_char(trunc(td.cre_on_date,'MON'), 
 'Month',
 'nls_date_language=american') TDATE ,
 coalesce(sum(td.amt),0) amt
from  trandetail td, tranheader th 
where th.batchid = td.batchid 
and td.status = 'FDSC' 
and td.ccy = 'USD' 
and th.pcid in (
  (select pty_id from bus_pty_hier bh 
    inner join bus_pty bp on bh.ASSOC_BUS_PTY_ID = BP.PTY_ID
    START WITH PARNT_BUS_PTY_ID = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ASSOC_BUS_PTY_ID = PARNT_BUS_PTY_ID) 
  union select 1 from dual) 
and td.cre_on_date > trunc(sysdate-180)
GROUP BY trunc(td.cre_on_date,'MON') 
ORDER BY trunc(td.cre_on_date,'MON') asc
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the other four months from the data because they don't exist. You need to generate a list of the potential months, and then outer join to your data. Something like (untested):

```
with months (month) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1 * (level - 1))
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select to_char(m.month, 'Month', 'nls_date_language=american') TDATE,
  coalesce(sum(t.amt),0) amt
from months m
left join (
  select trunc(td.cre_on_dt, 'MM') as month, td.amt
  from trandetail td
  inner join tranheader th 
  on th.batchid = td.batchid 
  where td.status = 'FDSC' 
  and td.ccy = 'USD' 
  and th.pcid in (
    select pty_id
    from bus_pty_hier bh 
    inner join bus_pty bp
    on bh.ASSOC_BUS_PTY_ID = BP.PTY_ID
    START WITH PARNT_BUS_PTY_ID = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ASSOC_BUS_PTY_ID = PARNT_BUS_PTY_ID
    union select 1 from dual
  )
  and td.cre_on_date >= add_mknths(trunc(sysdate), -6) -- maybe trunc MM again
) t
on t.month = m.month
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER BY m.mknth
```

The `months` CTE gives the first day of each of the last six months. I've essentially made most of your original query into an inline view (but it could be another CTE) because it has its own joins, but you can probably untangle that so this is a starting point really. From that inline view you get the month and amount from each transaction, and those are outer joined to the master list of momths before the aggregation and coalesce are done.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help, Now i'm getting error ''ORA-00904: "TD"."AMT": invalid identifier,  Can you please help to resolve this?

Comment: @user1127643 - well, I said it was untested *8-) I hadn't changed the table alias in the sum. Updated.